# Dojo Richtext editor Toolbar is not styling properly

Tags: dojo, rich-text-editor

I am creating richtext editor using dojo. I have applied extraPlugin features to this rich text editor. It's working properly but toolbar options are not getting wrapped.

[image]

As you can see Font section is not getting wrapped.
Can anyone help me??

Please refer following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_static/js/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

        <script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Editor","dijit/_editor/plugins/FontChoice", "dijit/_editor/plugins/TextColor"]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" id="editor1" data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){console.log('editor1 onChange handler: ' + arguments[0])},
        plugins:['cut','copy','paste','|','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','subscript','superscript','|', 'indent', 'outdent', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight','|','foreColor','hiliteColor',{name:'dijit/_editor/plugins/FontChoice', command:'fontName', generic:true}]">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *Minimal, Reproducible Source Code Example* of your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply. I have found it's solution.

Comment: it would still benefit the community if you *edited* your question with more details and then posted an answer to your own question with the solution. :)

Comment: Hope it will be helpful now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one plugin available in dojo editor to break toolbar line.
You can refer this link for this:

[Dojo ToolbarLineBreak](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/editor/plugins/ToolbarLineBreak.html)

Solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_static/js/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

        <script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Editor","dijit/_editor/plugins/FontChoice", "dijit/_editor/plugins/TextColor","dojox/editor/plugins/ToolbarLineBreak"]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" id="editor1" data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){console.log('editor1 onChange handler: ' + arguments[0])},
        plugins:['cut','copy','paste','|','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','subscript','superscript','|', 'indent', 'outdent', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight','||','foreColor','hiliteColor',{name:'dijit/_editor/plugins/FontChoice', command:'fontName', generic:true}]">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Add one more plugin "dojox/editor/plugins/ToolbarLineBreak" and use "||" in plugin prop to break line where you want.

Hope if some one finding solution then it will help them.